# Inform server about device local IP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a device that works as a webserver at a local network.

What I want to do is to send the local IP of this device to an external Server (which I have access to) so, when I visit the external Server to be able to be redirected to the local webserver.

Actually what I need is the user to be able to visit the local webserver without having to type the local address of the device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that the external server needs to act like a reverse proxy server ?

Comment: I think that proxy server is a good way to define it.

Comment: that basically sounds like dyndns or a similiar service. Also it's something you should either ask on serverfault or softwarerecs.

Comment: Not sure how you would do this without someone manually getting the address.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to let a user connect to your external server, but the external server redirects the user to a local server.

I guess a router of some kind will do, as it will redirect the incoming connection to your local server. Maybe (I am no networking engineer) you could use something like a PFSense box and make only one rule, that your external server gets directed to your local server.

As I said, I'm no networking engineer and I haven't woked with this yet, but maybe this can help you a little bit. I'm sorry for the incomplete answer, but this is all I can do.